# in glib library I don't understand that why does union data[2] of struct _GValue have 2 elements?

Tags: c, gtk, glib

according to struct _GValue as below:

```
struct _GValue
{
  /*< private >*/
  GType     g_type;

  /* public for GTypeValueTable methods */
  union {
    gint    v_int;
    guint   v_uint;
    glong   v_long;
    gulong  v_ulong;
    gint64      v_int64;
    guint64     v_uint64;
    gfloat  v_float;
    gdouble v_double;
    gpointer    v_pointer;
  } data[2];
};
```

first issue:

why there is 2 element data? data[0] representes value of g_type,but what does data[1] store? I don't understand that why does data[2] have 2 elements?

second issue:

in union data[2] this v_pointer stores other type except foundation type such as G_TYPE_INT,G_TYPE_LONG and so on. from v_int to v_double they store value of foundation type, if g_type is not fundation type data[0] use which type stores value of its type?so I guess that it use v_pointer to store pointer of this value. I don't know if I understand the issue of principle is correct?

if anybody have any idea for me ,thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Comments in gobject/gvalue.h,

```
/**
 * GValue:
 *
 * An opaque structure used to hold different types of values.
 * The data within the structure has protected scope: it is accessible only
 * to functions within a #GTypeValueTable structure, or implementations of
 * the g_value_*() API. That is, code portions which implement new fundamental
 * types.
 * #GValue users cannot make any assumptions about how data is stored
 * within the 2 element @data union, and the @g_type member should
 * only be accessed through the G_VALUE_TYPE() macro.
 */
```

Based on the current implementation, data[1] stores the attributes/state of GValue object.  And for the value contents fit into a pointer, such as objects or strings, data[0].v_pointer is used.  But users cannot make any assumptions about how data is stored, it could be changed in future.

Comment: you said this comment within gvalue.h  I also looked at,but I quote your explain:"GValue users cannot make any assumptions about how data is stored within the 2 element @data union",I entirely don't understand this sentence. because I entirely don't know that what data[1] stores?  you said "data[1] stores the attributes/state of GValue object". you can specifically explain this issue and use example of source code for me .thank you in advance.

Comment: One examples is, G_VALUE_NOCOPY_CONTENTS, it's stored in data[1].v_uint to indicate the value contents may be considered "static" for the duration of the @value lifetime. Or say, value_free function should only free its pointer without a specific flag for static storage.